Replacement of furnace draft inducer
Have a tempstar furnace and my furnace draft inducer went bad. Trying to figure out which one I can replace it with.
It's a Fasco
Here are my numbers No. 7002-2633
Type U02B
V-115
Hz 60
Amp 1.6
Class B
Rpm 3000
Hoping someone can help on replacement. Thanks

Look up the specs (cubic feet or cubic meters or liters per second, and suction in inches of water or pascals) for the fan number you have. Or just get the same fan again.

When you replace the motor,  there will be a plastic plate that regulates the volume of air delivered by the fan installed in the throat of the old fan. Take that piece and install it on the new assembly when you change it.
